# How to make multiple fetch requests inside Firebase functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make 2 fetch requests inside a function which runs periodically.

```
exports.scheduledPay = functions.pubsub.schedule('1 of month 07:00').timeZone('America/New_York').onRun((context) => {
  //1. fetch for getting token ...
  //2. fetch for making Paypal batch request using that token
    fetch("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payouts", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {"Authorization":"Basic QWJ4aUhTaWM5cmp2NUpQdEV2WUhaMi1hWmVySWFoTHdDVDEza004UURLY3RMWGtXN3lpTFRfVGpFVllVMXB5NFhKcGtxXzdYSVpYRmhkaFc6RVBUbUVZSWg2OE1FVG9FSjEyT0lHdzFKWkFGNTVza2Q2SjNiRmpLYkxMTEJiOTY3akRhQkdRREt1S29yTWN4amZ3Rm00X0VCa1dvUzJkejn="},
      body: {"grant_type":"client_credentials"},
      redirect: 'follow'
    })
    .then(response => {return response.text()})
    .then(result => {console.log(result);
      return null;
    })
    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

However, I keep on getting this error.

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
    at exports.scheduledAward.functions.pubsub.schedule.timeZone.onRun (/workspace/index.js:230:5)
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:130:23)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:199:28)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Hi Dinaol, welcome to SO! Your question seems to have a subtext "here's my problem, solve it for me", which unfortunately is not what SO is for. For starters, the body of the question does not even have a question, only statements. Have you tried researching the error message that you're getting? Literally the first search result on Google gives you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions run in a nodejs JavaScript environment.  This is very different than browser JavaScript environments.  You won't have access to the `fetch()` function that browsers provide - that explains the error message.

What you will need to do instead is use some other type of HTTP client library built for nodejs.  There are a lot of popular options out there, and I recommend doing a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=node%20js%20http%20request%20module&) to find one.